# Camel HttpOperationFailedException not being caught

Tags: apache-camel

I'm testing exception handling in Camel, and noticed an odd behaviour.  I have an http component with deliberately throws a 404 Error. Camel would then throw a `HttpOperationFailedException` created by `org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException`  I'm using onWhen to distinguish between different status codes:

This is a sample of the approach for a 404:

```
onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
    .onWhen(new Predicate() {
        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
            HttpOperationFailedException ex = exchange.getProperty(
                    Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,
                    HttpOperationFailedException.class);
            logger.warn("*** 404 Error ***");
            return (ex.getStatusCode() == 404);
        }
    }).handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0);
```

But it never gets executed.

So then I tried this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .onWhen(new Predicate() {
        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
            Object ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
            logger.error(ex.getClass());
            return (true);
        }
    }).handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0);
```

And the logger always shows `class org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException`

Any help would be great! I'm using Camel 2.17.1.

Comment: I found the problem.  I was using `import org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException` instead of `import org.apache.camel.http.HttpOperationFailedException`

Comment: I now only see `org.apache.camel.http.common` one(deprecated) and `org.apache.camel.http.base` one, which is not deprecated. Dependency is `camel-http-base`, version `3.14.1`